# How to get AppointmentItem.BillingInformation property using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: graph

I'm trying to expand the field `BillingInformation` in my exchange calendar event with `graph api`. Querying the event works fine but I cannot get the Property: `BillingInformation`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name BillingInformation')

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name BillingInformation' and ep/value ne null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with this query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8535')

Answer (score 0):

Managed Graph API library can help you construct correct extended property queries:

https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi

You can take a look at this test case how to retrieve property, example is for message, but principle applies to events as well

https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.ManagedAPI.FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests/MessageTestDefinition.cs